# When a backdoor is installed in a device, does it become vulnerable to 'everyone', or only to the attacker?

Tags: ip, backdoor

I'm running tests on my devices. But I'm scared that by doing this, I will make my devices vulnerable. If I executed a backdoor sent to me (being an app with a payload on it, or doc, or email, etc), my device will become vulnerable to only the IP of the attacker (me), determined on the payload? Or it will be vaguely vulnerable to everyone capable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what sort of payload you're deploying.  For example, a reverse TCP payload would trigger the target to make an outbound connection to the attacking IP address you've specified, and so would not be vulnerable to someone else trying to take advantage of it.  On the other hand, a TCP listener on the target might accept connections from any IP address, and therefore be vulnerable to anyone who happened to scan your target at the right time.

Comment: Even using tools like Metasploit ? Sometimes i wonder if those tools could listen the device i'm listening, since i navegate trough my (target) devices using the metasploit terminal interface

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the type of payload you've selected.  Anything *_reverse_* in Metasploit should be safe for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tool in use. A typical Metasploit listener is open to anybody who connects to it. Some other tools may require authentication (crypto keys or passwords) in order to connect.

Comment: And if i execute an reverse tcp payload, made on metasploit, and  setted my ip as the   listener, my device (target) will still be open to anybody ?

Comment: No, see @gowenfawr's answer regarding payload types.